# How to use existing HTML source in mainpage

Tags: doxygen

For a C programming assignment I generated a web page describing the assignment. It is HTML source. I have added doxygen comments to all the provided C code and generated documentation.

It would be nice to put the content of the assignment file on the mainpage tab generated by
doxygen. I took one of the C files and added the following snippet to it

```
/** @mainpage Fall 2012 Programming Assignment 1 - Bit Fields in C
 *  \include "description.html"
 */
```

What I see on the resulting generated mainpage tab is the raw HTML, not a nicely rendered output. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Rahter than using the `\include` command try using the [`\htmlinclude`](/manual/commands.html#cmdhtmlinclude) command.